# Howto replace elements of one list of values by elements of second list interactively?

Tags: vim

When writing sometimes I have to replace several different words successively, say a1 -> a2, b1->b2, c1->c2 and so on.

For this I manually edit the command history so I start with

```
:s/a1/a2/gc
```

after go and replace a1 and a2 by b1 and b2, do the substitution and continue to the next item.

The work flow I would like to have would be something like:

```
:let in = ['a1', 'b1', 'c1']
:let out = ['a2', 'b2', 'c2']
:call ReplaceAllWithConfirmation(in, out)
```

where ReplaceAllWithConfirmation would be a function that would perform the the substitutions but asking me to confirm each time.

Would this be possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to write a function. Just run this command:

```
:%s/[a-c]1/\={'a1':'a2','b1':'b2','c1':'c2'}[submatch(0)]/gc
```

You can have a expression after `\=`.

Comment: That's a clever use of a replace-expression, though the pattern repetition and syntax would still be cumbersome to type each time.

Answer (score 2):

With Tim Pope's [Abolish plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1545), your example would be

```
%Subvert/{a,b,c}1/{}2/g
```

Answer (score 0):

After I asked the questions I came up with this function and mapping that almost does what I wanted. This is not as elegant as the two other answers, but it can be adapted to execute a succession of general commands specified by a list pausing in between each of the commands so I am writing here.

```
function! MyLatexReplaceText(...)
  if a:0 > 0
    if a:0 != 2
      echom "provide two lists to the function"
      return ''
    endif
    let g:replace_list_in = a:1
    let g:replace_list_out = a:2
    let g:replace_ncur = 0
  endif
  if a:0 == 0 && !exists("g:replace_ncur")
    let g:replace_list_in = ['a1', 'b1', 'c1']
    let g:replace_list_out = ['a2', 'b2', 'c2']
    let g:replace_ncur = 0
  endif
  if g:replace_ncur == len(g:replace_list_in)
    let g:replace_cmd = ":echom 'reached end of list'\<CR>"
    let g:replace_ncur = -1
  else
    let range_ = "'<,'>"
    let extra_flags = 'gc'
    let g:replace_cmd = ':' .range_ . "s/" .  g:replace_list_in[g:replace_ncur] 
          \ . "/" . g:replace_list_out[g:replace_ncur] . "/" . extra_flags
          \ . "\<CR>"
    call histadd("cmd", g:replace_cmd)
  endif
  let g:replace_ncur += 1
  return g:replace_cmd
endfunction
nnoremap <silent><expr> <Leader>ns MyLatexReplaceText()
```